# Is it possible to send WhatsApp messages over external clients?

Tags: xmpp, whatsapp

When I know an XMPP ID (something like `[phonenumber]@s.whatsapp.net`) what else do I need to send a WhatsApp message?

Answer (score 1):

you will also need a password, which may be a md5 hash, you will need to reverse the md5 Hash in, every xmpp account has a username and a password

Comment: @but Setup `xmpp` and whatsapp plugins on pidgin, but both are not working getting `Server closed the connection` error, Have you tried ?